# Cocos2d-x - encode base64 string from sprite or texture data

Tags: c++, base64, cocos2d-x, encode

How create base64 string from image data, encode base64 from image data,
Ill try like this

```
CCRenderTexture* r = CCRenderTexture::create(sprite->getTexture()->getPixelsWide(), sprite->getTexture()->getPixelsHigh());
r->beginWithClear(1, 1, 1, 0);
sprite->visit();
r->end();
CCImage *img = r->newCCImage();
unsigned char *data = img->getData();
int len = img->getDataLen();
str = base64_encode(data, len);


return str;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,
Need to read the image as a text file and decode in base64,
I misunderstood about the work img-> getData ();

```
std::string str;
unsigned long pSize = 0;
unsigned char*filecont =  CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->getFileData("file.png", "rb", &pSize);
cout<<filecont;
str = base64_encode(filecont, pSize);
cout<<str;
return str;
```